# Angular transclude in table cell element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-transclude

I have an attribute directive which just adds a class name to the element on which it is applied. That attribute directive is applied to a table cell `<td>` element. When I have `transclude: true` in the directive definition it replaces the table cell content. I cannot figure out why.  Can someone help me out since I'm facing this issue for the first time?

My understanding is by definition transclude should contain whatever content was in there already but not sure why I'm facing this issue. Can someone suggest a solution?

Here is the code,

```
angular.module('app', []).directive('indicator', function () {

return {
    restrict: 'AC',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    link: function ($scope, $elem, $attrs) {
        if($attrs.type) {
            $elem.addClass('indicator-'+$attrs.type);
        }
        else {
            $elem.addClass('indicator');    
        }
    }
};});
```

the directive definition in html would look like,

```
<td indicator type="someType">5000</td>
```

As I mentioned earlier if I have transclude as false then it works as expected. But when I have transclude as true it adds the class and the table cell content disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of both the `replace` and `transclude` properties.

You obviously don't want to *replace* the element and [`replace` is deprecated](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-replace-deprecated-will-be-removed-in-next-major-release-i-e-v2-0-) anyway.

You are also not using the `ngTransclude` directive (in fact, you have no directive template at all) so there's no need to `transclude`.

You can simplify the whole thing down to

```
.directive('indicator', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AC',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.addClass(attrs.type ? 'indicator-' + attrs.type : 'indicator');
        }
    };
})
```